# Where's the editor: libplist-util and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, plist

I need to modify some compressed/binary plist files in an IPA. An IPA is an iOS's APK. Tere's a libplist-utils for Ubuntu and I installed them (I don't have access to my MacBook at the moment).

Running `plist` from the command line results in nothing:

```
$ plist -convert xml1 916CD34C-4D41-41B7-9266-2DCAC416E2D1/example.app/Settings.bundle/Root.plist -out test.xml
No command 'plist' found, did you mean:
 Command 'pqlist' from package 'ncpfs' (universe)
 Command 'flist' from package 'nmh' (universe)
 ...
```

And:

```
$ plutil -convert xml1 916CD34C-4D41-41B7-9266-2DCAC416E2D1/example.app/Settings.bundle/Root.plist -out test.xml
plutil: command not found
```

The best I can tell, an empty package was installed:

```
$ apt-cache showpkg libplist-utils
Package: libplist-utils
Versions: 
1.10-1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 255d33606ccb9b406f4ba77acd8b0df6
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_universe_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 255d33606ccb9b406f4ba77acd8b0df6

Reverse Depends: 
  libplist-utils:i386,libplist-utils
Dependencies: 
1.10-1 - libc6 (2 2.2.5) libplist1 (2 0.13) libplist-utils:i386 (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
1.10-1 - 
Reverse Provides:
```

There is no man page either.

What exactly did `libplist-utils` install? Where's the editor? How do I edit plist files on a Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 2):

The name of the executable has changed to plistutil. It's not an editor, it only convert to text format.